# SQL Server : creating a procedure to insert multiple values to a table at once - without knowing how many in advance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How can I create a procedure that will insert a few values into a table (which are songs ID's), depending on how many values I (or the user) want to put in the table at once, in other words -  without knowing how many values in advance ? 

(without knowing many songs the user will choose to put in).

It's a playlists table that has many playlists and each playlist has many songs IDs.

**The user interface is React Native and I'm working with C# WebService**.

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE [Playlists_Songs]
(
    SongID INT NOT NULL 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Songs](Song_ID),
    PlaylistID INT NOT NULL 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Playlists](Playlist_ID)
    PRIMARY KEY (SongID, PlaylistID)
)
```

The procedure I want to change:

```sql
CREATE PROC Add_Playlist_Songs
@songID int, --- don't know how many @songID's will be chosen by the user to insert in.
@playlistID int 
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [site15].[Playlists_Songs] ([PlaylistID], [SongID])
VALUES (@songID , @playlistID)
END

GO
```

Songs table:

[image: songs table]

Any suggestions?

P.S

I have only a procedure to create a playlist with user Id, playlist name and image, yet.

If any more details or edit to the question is needed please tell me.

Comment: Do you mean, insert multiple rows without knowing how many in advance? In that case, research table-valued parameters (2012+ IIRC).

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Show us where you have the songs. Are in an array? a csv string? tell us more

Comment: Why dont call the procedure with each song?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have the songs in an array, a table of songs. each songs has name, path, ID.

Comment: Show us an example and what is your expected result

Comment: Many songs ID's  to one playlist ID

Comment: Again show us an example. I dont see any  reason why you can't do a loop in C# and call your current procedure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185710/discussion-between-sup-dr-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Can you please tell me when do you mean by "do a loop in C# " ? I need it to be with one user press on the submit button.

Comment: What part you dont understand? you dont know loops? again show us current code so we can help you more

Answer (score 3):

Try to see Table-Valued Parameters. [As MSDN says:](http://Table-valued%20parameters%20are%20declared%20by%20using%20user-defined%20table%20types.%20You%20can%20use%20table-valued%20parameters%20to%20send%20multiple%20rows%20of%20data%20to%20a%20Transact-SQL%20statement%20or%20a%20routine,%20such%20as%20a%20stored%20procedure%20or%20function,%20without%20creating%20a%20temporary%20table%20or%20many%20parameters.)

> Table-valued parameters are declared by using user-defined table
>   types. You can use table-valued parameters to send multiple rows of
>   data to a Transact-SQL statement or a routine, such as a stored
>   procedure or function, without creating a temporary table or many
>   parameters.

Create `User defined Table Type`:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.SongIds
AS TABLE
(
  ID int
);
```

Then just use this parameter and other parameters in your stored procedures:

```
CREATE PROC Add_Playlist_Songs
@SongIds AS dbo.SongIds READONLY
@playlistID int 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [site15].[Playlists_Songs] ([PlaylistID], [SongID])
    SELECT 
      s.ID
    , playlistID 
    FROM @SongIds s

END

GO
```

An example of calling:

```
DECLARE @SongIds  SongIds;
DECLARE @playlistID INT = 5

INSERT INTO @SongIds
(
    ID
)
VALUES
 (1)
,(2)
,(3)

EXEC Add_Playlist_Songs @SongIds , @playlistID
```